# Не подключаются несколько событий onTextChanged на каждый EditText

Tags: java, android

Когда я пытаюсь присвоить одно событие onTextChanged к одному EditText, чтобы значение из этого EditText записалось в  другой EditText,  всё работает хорошо. Но когда я делаю три onTextChanged на каждый из трёх EditText отдельно каждому, приложение вылетает. Что делать? Заранее спасибо

```
package com.romatopotatos.physicalformulas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.Editable;

public class FDvigActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editS;
    EditText editV;
    EditText editT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_f_dvig);

        editS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sEdit);
        editV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vEdit);
        editT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tEdit);

        editS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){
                String s = editS.getText().toString();
                editT.setText(s);
                editV.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed){

            }
        });

        editV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){
                String v = editV.getText().toString();
                editT.setText(v);
                editS.setText(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed){

            }
        });

        editS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){
                String t = editT.getText().toString();
                editS.setText(t);
                editV.setText(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed){

            }
        });
    }

}
```

В приложении при вводе значения в одно поле должны  меняться значения в других полях. Но пока я сделал так, чтобы при вводе значения в одно поле, это же значение появлялось в других полях. Но при попытке ввести текст приложение не отвечает, экранная клавиатура на некоторое время "застревает"[image: Скриншот тестового приложения]

Comment: Приложите логи падения, код, так сказать довольно сложно, что именно Вы делаете не так. Есть подозрение, что происходит зацикливание и Вы из одного onTextChanged изменяете значение другого EditText и в этом же EditText вызывается onTextChanged и так по кругу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да похоже на зацикливание: editV.setText(t) вызывает у editV метод onTextChanged, который вызывает onTextChanged у двух остальных, и по экспоненте. Помимо этого у вас в коде ошибка - editS.addTextChangedListener вы добавляете два раза, второй раз вы должны на editT добавить слушатель.

Нужно добавить три boolean переменные stopV, stopS, stopT для блокировки зацикливания. **Код проверил, работает!**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editS;
EditText editV;
EditText editT;
boolean stopV;
boolean stopS;
boolean stopT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editS);
    editV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT);
    editT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editV);

    stopS=true;
    stopV=true;
    stopT=true;

    editS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if (stopS) {
                String sw = editS.getText().toString();
                stopT = false;
                stopV=false;
                editT.setText(sw);
                editV.setText(sw);
            }
            stopS=true;
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }


    });

    editV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if (stopV) {
                stopS = false;
                stopT = false;

                String v = editV.getText().toString();
                editT.setText(v);
                editS.setText(v);
            }
            stopV=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed){


        }
    });

    editT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ch, int i, int i1, int i2){

            if (stopT) {
                stopV=false;
                stopS=false;
                String t = editT.getText().toString();
                editS.setText(t);
                editV.setText(t);
            }
            stopT=true;

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed){
        }
    });
}
```

Xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mihail_lagarnikov.ru.shadowtest1.MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editV" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editS" />
```

Comment: Михаил, ваш способ не помогает

Comment: Изменил ответ, код проверил - он работает

Comment: Михаил, не могли бы вы показать Ваш xml-код. Может, я там что-то не то сделал.

Comment: Добавил, единственное различие у нас это id editText по разному названы.

Comment: Михаил, благодарю Вас, работает! Я понял свою ошибку.